# Une vieille femme vêtue de noir, accompagnée d'une ado, ont / est descendu(e)

Tags: accord

Bonjour,

*Roses de sang Roses d'Ouessant* de Janine Boissard :

> Une vieille femme vêtue de noir, accompagnée d'une ado, short au ras
> des fesses, portant un gros couffin d'osier, **ont** descendu à leur tour
> le sentier, la petite soutenant sa grand-mère.

Ça ne devrait pas être "**est** descendu**e**" ?

Answer (score 4):

Moi aussi, si j'avais écrit la phrase, j'aurais comme toi accordé le verbe en considérant qu'il n'y avait qu'un seul sujet : « une vieille femme », ce qui serait un accord strictement grammatical, « accompagnée d'une ado, short au ras des fesses, portant un gros couffin d'osier » n'étant qu'une apposition au sujet.

L'auteur a choisi de faire ici un accord sémantique et tient compte du fait que deux personnes font l'action, elle accorde donc le verbe avec un sujet pluriel. Cet accord est peu courant de nos jours il me semble<sup>1</sup>.

Si, au lieu d'avoir une proposition avec un adjectif apposé, un  « vieille femme » et « ado » avaient été coordonnés, l'accord grammatical se serait imposé.

- Une vieille femme vêtue de noir, **et** une ado, short au ras des fesses, portant un gros couffin d'osier, ont descendu...

---

Descendre : être ou avoir ?

- Elles ont descendu la montagne (verbe transitif) : c'est une action, un mouvement, on voit les deux personnes en train de descendre.
- Elles sont descendues **de** la montagne (verbe intransitif)  : on ne voit que le résultat final, c'est une constatation : elles sont déjà arrivées en bas.

J'ai délibérément remplacé « sentier » par « montagne » parce que, bien qu'on puisse imaginer un contexte où on descendrait **du** sentier, cela semble peu probable. Par contre il est très courant d'employer « descendre » de façon transitive pour dire qu'on descend une voie (une rue, une avenue, un sentier...) même s'il n'y a pas de pente très visible, pour diverses raisons comme le commente ci-dessous @Personne avec humour.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Je dis « de nos jours » car il est possible que ce n'ait pas toujours été le cas.</sup>

Comment: — « … il est très courant d'employer *descendre* de façon transitive pour dire qu'on descend une voie (une rue, une avenue, … » : soit pour dire que l'on “descend la rue” des numéros les plus élevés vers le début de la rue, soit pour dire que l'on se dirige vers la partie animée de la rue, soit pour dire qu'on est arrivé dans un endroit de la rue à toute vitesse ou en venant d'un autre endroit, soit parce que c'est la coutume de descendre “La rue de la Soif” dans les deux sens (la remontée est incluse dans la tournée des bistrots quand on ne la descend pas en zig-zag), …

Comment: …  soit parce que c'est l'expression du locuteur pour dire qu'il a emprunté la rue, soit parce que l'on descend la rue(sans tenir compte des numéros)  vers une autre rue, un autre lieu, soit …, soit parce que l'inventivité du langage familier n'a pas de limites :-)